# How to check if object within object exists

Tags: javascript, object, member, literals

It seems that the following technique for checking the existence of an object member produces an error because the 'bar' parent object hasn't been declared before the check, which means I either have to declare it before the check or use two 'typeof' expressions, either of which would be excess code:

```
var foo = {},
    newVal = (typeof foo.bar.myVal !== 'undefined' ? foo.bar.myVal : null );

Error: foo.bar is undefined
```

So, how do you check if a member within an undeclared object exists without producing an error?

I love javascript, but sometimes...

Comment: No tags in your subject line please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It can be done simply using the code below:

```
var newVal = (foo && foo.bar && typeof foo.bar.myVal !== 'undefined') ? foo.bar.myVal : foo.bar.myVal
```

A property is null or undefined, it will be evaluated as false so the above code will only process up to the first 'false' statement.

Comment: It seems this is one of JavaScripts failings. We should be able to check for the existence of object children without first having to check for the existence of the parent object.

Comment: That's an assumption that can be made if you are certain that the parent always exists.  Personally, if I'm passed an object as a parameter, I always check to see if the object is even valid.

Comment: That is no simply at all. Once you manually mistake check a return variable, maybe from a remote host API, you can crash your app.

Answer (score 6):

```
var newVal = ('foo' in window && // could be typeof foo !== 'undefined' if you want all scopes
             'bar' in foo &&
             'myVal' in foo.bar) ? foo.bar.myVal : null;
```

To be fair to javascript, that reads almost like natural language.

Comment: I'd add parentheses around the condition. Even though operator precedence might be OK it's more obvious with parens.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, I added them. I don't like them though. IMO it looks less obvious like that. Meh, I'll leave them.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest test is:

```
if (foo && foo.bar) {
  // play with foo.bar.myVal  ... 
}
```

Comment: isn't there a better way... for example you can easily check if object foo exists if you just type if (foo) , but if you want to check if (foo.a.b), can't browser tell if a doesn't exist then b doesn't either.

Comment: it matters because if i have object like a.b.c.d.e and i want to check if e exists i really have to go crazy with &&

Comment: @MuhammadUmer—unfortunately the language specification says that attempting to access a property of a non–existent object (attempting to access a property of *undefined*) must throw an error. You can wrap it in try..catch, but that's not considered good practice, has performance implications and is likely more code than using `&&`.

Comment: well it's really a pain, for example, if i'm getting a json from server, it could contain a complicated error message or complicated data. Error msg could look like this: `data.client.a.error.msg` or data: `data.client.oauth.about.user.name`

Comment: Do you know this other way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56261366/334963 ?

Comment: @Gabrielizalo—No, `if (foo?.bar)` has a syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks @RobG.. You are right. This works with a JS transpiler like Babel.. I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap it up into a method:

```
function checkGraph(obj, graphPath)
{
  var parts = graphPath.split(".");
  var root = obj;

  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++)
  {
    var part = parts[i];
    if (root[part] && root.hasOwnProperty(part))
      root = root[part];
    else
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Where you could call it as:

```
var foo = {},
    newVal = checkGraph(foo, "bar.myVal") ? foo.bar.myVal : null;
```

Comment: Yes thats the only way to do that. Otherwise its not simple at all.

Answer (score 1):

As [Matthew Abbott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/357693/matthew-abbott) gave in his response, you can write a method for it to use it later if you do a lot of diving into child properties where the whole object or somewhere along the chain can be null. Below is my implementation using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/).

```
checkGraph(obj, graphPath) {
    if (obj) {
      let root = obj;
      _.each(graphPath.split('.'), part => {
        if (root[part]) {
          root = root[part];
        } else {
          return false; // bad property
        }
      });
      return true;
    }
    return false; // bad object
  }
```

You can call the method like this:

```
if (this.checkGraph(object, 'property.subproperty') {
    // do thing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another way is you use a *JS transpiler* like **Babel**:

```
if (foo?.bar) {
  // play with foo.bar.myVal  ... 
}
```

Comment: The optional chaining operator (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) will be part of Javascript in the future