# if typeof obj.prop === "undefined" in Node not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using the following in a Jade view file with Express 4.0 and Node

```
 if typeof user.email === "undefined"
```

This will produce the following error:

```
    //console.info(user.email) -> undefined
    TypeError: C:\var\www\stage.mayfieldafc.com\src\app\views\includes\header.jade:8
        6|         div(class='right')
        7|             a(href='/stats') Personal Stats
      > 8|             if typeof user.email === "undefined"
        9|                 a(href='/login') Sign In
        10|             else
        11|                 a(href='/account') Your Account
```

How can I safely check it a variable is set in node using express?

You might think this would work: [Jade - Template Engine: How to check if a variable exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070841/jade-template-engine-how-to-check-if-a-variable-exists) But it gives the exact same error.

Comment: `if ( user && user.email ) { } `

Comment: So `user` is undefined? Then you need to check for that first before accessing `.email`.

Comment: Good thinking... Interesting though. Why can't I just check if something is undefined straight out?

Comment: Closely related to [How to check if object within object exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548256/how-to-check-if-object-within-object-exists)

Comment: Also, with checking for `user` first, this will return true. Ignore the later and then display `Your Account` to a user who isn't yet logged in.